# C++ making each decimal in a double into array elements?

Tags: c++, arrays, double, decimal, element

(This is for an exercise) I'm trying to create a program that takes a double like 1.2041 and makes each decimal into an element in an array.

Through a loop I want the array to end up like this: `ar[0] = 0.2; ar[1] = 0.00;  ar[2] = 0.004;  ar[3] = 0.0001;`

After that I'm going to add the decimals together and end up with 0,2041 but I can't seem to find any way to reach out to each decimal alone.

I tried with multiplying and subtracting but I can't seem to get it to work.

Anyone know a simple way of making each decimal in a double into their own separate elements in an array?

Comment: `ar[0] = 0,2` doesn't assign 0.2 to the 0th element of the array. This is the comma operator; it will assign `0` to the array element and then evaluate `2` (which is a no-op). Use `.` for a decimal *point* instead. Also, `fmod()` (and/or `modf()`).

Comment: Oh, didn't see that was a typo in the question. Didn't actually write that in the code ^^ thanks

Comment: Does your input include coma ( , ) too?

Comment: Edited it now. My input did not include a comma

Comment: @user3797804 actually that doesn't matter (a lot). hint: do this the same way you would extract the digits from an integer. Repeated division and modulo operations are the key.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: since fractional decimal values cannot, in general, be represented using a binary floating representation, extracting fractional digits doesn't work that way at all: you'd get the underlying approximation of the original decimal value rather than the digits of the decimal.

Comment: Show code that doesn't work, desired results and actual results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are keen to implement Dragon4 (see "How to Print Floating-Point Numbers Accurately" by Guy L.Steele Jr. and Jon L.White) you'd be best off to format the `double` value into a string, e.g., using `std::to_string()`, and compute the respective digit value [approximations] from that.

When representing a decimal value with fractional digits in a `double` which is usually represented using a binary floating point representation the value generally get rounded. For example, it is impossible to exactly represent `0.1` using a `double`. Instead, the closest representable value will be stored. When using an appropriate algorithm to recover a decimal representation, e.g., Dragon4 or Grisu (where the latter is typically faster but sometimes falls back to Dragon4 as far as I understand it) the original rounding is taken into account. These algorithms are somewhat non-trivial. You can find the source of a variation of Dragon4 in [`dtoa.c`](http://www.netlib.org/fp/) by David Gay. You may want to have a look at more details in the article [Here be dragons: advances in problems you didn’t even know you had](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2011/06/29/here-be-dragons-advances-in-problems-you-didnt-even-know-you-had/).

When you use a naive approach trying to deduce each digit you'll get a value but at best you are getting the value actually represented by the `double`. For example, your value `1.2041` is represented as `1.204099999999999948130380289512686431407928466796875`. The easiest way to see how a value is represented is to use the [IEEE-754 Analysis](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/): get two analyzers, enter the value into the first one, take the hexadecimal representation (in your case `3FF343FE5C91D14E`), and dump it into the second one. It will show the exact decimal value used by the `double`.

Comment: Maybe replace it with its [webarchive version](http://web.archive.org/web/20150330014345/http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2011/06/29/here-be-dragons-advances-in-problems-you-didnt-even-know-you-had/).

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply by 10^n, and turn the result into an int, you'll get the whole number up to the wanted decimal. If you then get the remainder of that number divided with 10, you'll get only the number.

Then, you divide with 10^n and get the decimal:

```
(double)((int)(number/pow(10,n))%10)/pow(10,n)
```

That should do the trick.

NOTE: This code requires "math.h", number is the whole number, and n the decimal. n=1 is the first decimal.

Note 2: As Dietmar Kühl noted, this code has problems with the last decimal, as can be seen here: http://ideone.com/xOracn I'm looking for a workaround or a fix.

Comment: Note that this approach will get the last digits wrong quite frequently. For example, the last digit will be wrong for `1.2045` (you can easily try the output of `std::cout << int(x * 10) << '\n';` where `x` is initialized to `1.2045` (note that using a constant will probably yield the correct value because constant folding by compilers has become too good; however, with dynamic value you'll get wrong results). Also note that you can't salvage the result, e.g., by adding `0.5`: although this will fix some values it will break others.

Comment: The way to fix that is known under the name Dragon4 or Grisu (the latter is an improved algorithm which is faster and sometimes falls back to Dragon4): it is non-trivial and pretty much amounts to formatting the `double`.

Comment: I'm editing my answer to make this failure clear until I solve it.

Comment: You may want to have a look at ["Here be Dragons"](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2011/06/29/here-be-dragons-advances-in-problems-you-didnt-even-know-you-had/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I usually try to evade the doubles as much as I can.